# Ionic + Cordova : How to receive the push notifications after the system reboot?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm using the Ionic push notifications integration for the Android and iOS.

I just switched from debug mode into production (see link: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-full-setup). I am able to receive the push notifications if application is running in the background. But when the device is rebooted and the push notification is send, device will not receive the push notification until the app is started.

I would like to ask that is possible solve this situation and how?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you using the Ionic Push or a plugin?

Comment: Ionic Push, but it's based on the Cordova push plugin.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem in a project and fixed it by referencing APN & GCM directly on server side and switching to a plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) instead of Ionic Push.
Hope it helps.